# Django and Apache2 error - You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: python, django, apache, linux-mint

I am trying to deploy my django app to Digital Ocean with apache web server. I am following [this](http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/) and [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-mod_wsgi-to-serve-applications-on-ubuntu-12-04) tutorials. However, when I try accessing my site remotely, I get the error:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

My virtual host file for the site i.e. teenvestor, looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName teenvestor.co.uk
        ServerAlias www.teenvestor.co.uk
        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/teenvestor/teenvestor/apache/django.wsgi

        Alias /static/ /opt/teenvestor/teenvestor/static/
        <Location "/static/">
            Options -Indexes
        </Location >
</VirtualHost>
```

I have enabled the site.
My django.wsgi file looks like:

```
import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('/opt/teenvestor/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/opt/teenvestor/teenvestor')
sys.path.append('/opt/teenvestor/teenvestor/teenvestor')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'teenvestor.settings'

# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("~/opt/teenvestor/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

PS: I am using virtualenv. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This bit doesn't look right:

```
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("~/opt/teenvestor/bin/activate_this.py")
```

Where is your virtualenv? In `/opt` or `~/opt`? They are two different places. Everywhere else, you're referring to `/opt`.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is similar to yours and works fine. I have the import of django and the django.setup()

```
import os
import sys
import site
import django
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger("")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)-8s %(messages)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

sys.stdout = sys.stderr
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join


# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('/home/xxxxxxx/workspace/djangoEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/home/xxxxxxx/workspace/djangoEnv/xxxxxxx')
sys.path.append('/home/xxxxxxx/workspace/djangoEnv/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'xxxxxxx.settings'



# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("/home/xxxxxxx/workspace/djangoEnv/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

django.setup()

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```